# Tiny Scrollbar error on ajax added elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I have a page where I'm trying to apply the tinyscrollbar plugin to some div loaded through AJAX. The plugin breaks and I get the `oViewport.obj[0] is undefined` error in the console.

The same code works on other divs that already exists on the page. Any ideas? Thanks

The CODE is:

```
$("#sidebar-right").html("<div>bla bla bla <div class='tinyscroll'>bla bla bla</div> bla bla bla</div>");
$(".tinyscroll").tinyscrollbar({sizethumb: 24, wheel: 10});
```

Comment: I updated the question with the code :)

Comment: If you found the answer, post it... This is a "Question & _Answer_" website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was adding all the html markup ( needed by tinyscroll ) to the div I wanted through jquery (using `$(selector).wrap(some elements)`). I tested to see if the new alements exists in the DOM and they were present, but tinyscroll couldn't find them. Now I added that html markup to the ajax response itself and it's working.

But I still can't figure it out why it works on other divs not loaded via ajax.